# How to check Spark configuration from command line?

Tags: linux, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

Basically, I want to check a property of Spark's configuration, such as "spark.local.dir" through command line, that is, without writing a program. Is there a method to do this?

Comment: Do you mean parsing `spark-defaults.conf`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no option of viewing the spark configuration properties from command line.

Instead you can check it in spark-default.conf file.  Another option is to view from webUI.

The application web UI at http://driverIP:4040 lists Spark properties in the “Environment” tab. Only values explicitly specified through spark-defaults.conf, SparkConf, or the command line will appear. For all other configuration properties, you can assume the default value is used.

For more details, you can refer [Spark Configuration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

Answer (score 5):

Following command print your conf properties on console

```
 sc.getConf.toDebugString
```

Comment: Kind of, but this is a Scala command, not a shell command

Answer (score 4):

We can check in Spark shell using below command :

```
scala> spark.conf.get("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions")
res33: String = 200
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html. Spark provides three locations to configure the system:

- Spark properties control most application parameters and can be set
  by using a SparkConf object, or through Java system properties.
- Environment variables can be used to set per-machine settings, such the IP address, through the conf/spark-env.sh script on each
  node.
- Logging can be configured through log4j.properties.

I haven't heard about method through command line.

Answer (score 1):

Master command to check spark config from CLI

```
sc._conf.getAll()
```